# Cannot link SYSV static lib with GNU/Linux

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, abi

I want to link to some external static lib, let's say `somelib`. I'm trying to do this by `FIND_LIBRARY` in cmake and it seems to work ok - cmake finds `libsomelib.a` but there is a problem with linking:

`` (somelib.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC ``

I'm sure `somelib` is compiled with PIC enabled. Some interesting things:
`file somelib.o` shows `FpgaPicAPI.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped` and here's the `file` output of one of my project's object file: `ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), not stripped`. As far as I know, `SYSV` means "this object file does not use any OS-specific features" but can I link such object files with different OS/ABI? The second thing is compiler version: `somelib` uses gcc 5.4.0 and I have to use 4.8.5 but I believe it's not the problem - Ive got side project using `somelib` and it works okay with gcc 4.8 (executable becames `SYSV` btw). No idea what to check next.

Comment: "I'm sure somelib is compiled with PIC enabled." Your linker is telling you otherwise, and it's pretty good at linker stuff. You need to look at the relocations in the object, the `file` output is not sufficient.

Comment: @Mat: any of my known methods of determining PIC presance works, but the authors of this lib are sure that this is PIC version. They gave me `libfpga.a` and `libfpgapic.a` files. I think it's safe to assume that it's not the problem here. I googled this "relocation against" and solutions were really weird - no file found, no symlink, no PIC and much more.

Comment: The linker understands the object file format and relocation types, and it is telling you that that object file has at least one relocation that is not usable in the way you are asking. If you don't believe your linker, look at the relocations in that file (with readelf or objdump or similar) and manually check them all.

Comment: I will double check this with authors of lib. But then how is it possible that it links properly with my side project?